# how to troubleshoot libertine x apps?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, development, debugging, libertine

Some of the apps in custom libertine container fails to launch, crashes randomly and some systematically. On normal desktop launching the application throught terminal casually provides at least some traces which allows to find the workaround or find the bug and suply the fix. How to troubleshoot/debug the x apps in the libertine container?

I am using bq m10 tablet (armhf vivid chroot type container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*We discussed these issues on freenode #ubuntu-libertine, recapping here.*

You can find logs for libertine applications in the `$HOME/.cache/upstart` directory. For information about individual apps, the file pattern to look for is `application-legacy-$CONTAINERID_$APPNAME_0.0-.log`. For instance, if you launch gedit from the puritine container (default on UT), the log will be available in `$HOME/.cache/upstart/application-legacy-puritine_gedit_0.0-.log`.

There might also be some interesting information in `$HOME/.cache/upstart/unity8.log` for general Unity 8 messages, or `$HOME/.cache/upstart/scope-registry.log` for messages pertaining to running the scope.

Note that vivid is no longer supported by app developers, so not all applications are guaranteed to work. There's also the possibility that app developers will release non-working armhf builds of their apps due to the small user pool.

Comment: thanks, I think this is going to be useful for more people